# Browserstack setup on appium desktop

Tags: appium, browserstack, inspector

I'm unable to connect to Browserstack on Appium Dekstop. The error I get back isn't very helpful either.  This is the setup I have:

```
Remote Host: http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub

Remote Port: <empty>

Capabilities:

{
[![enter image description here][1]][1]  "app": "bs://<address of app uploaded to Browserstack>",
  "device": "iPhone 7 Plus"
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to inspect elements on your app? If yes, you will not be able to connect your Appium Desktop to any cloud service. You will need to connect a physical device to your system or launch an emulator to work with Appium Desktop

Comment: any clue on how to connect to the ios simulator then?

Comment: If you are using a Mac, simply install the latest version of XCode and Appium desktop with automatically launch simulator once you specify deviceName, platformName, platformVersion and app capabilities. (By default you will have the latest ios version on simulators, for older versions, you will be required to explicitly download the ios version through XCode)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to load app to browser stack.
curl -u "username:tocken" \
  -X POST "https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/upload" \
  -F "file=@/path/to/app/file/Application-debug.apk"

as a response you will receive the value for "app" capability.